# Why my email sent by phpmailer consider as junk(header included)?

Tags: email, header, phpmailer, send

I use phpmailer to send emails. the phpmailer reconfigured with SMTP perfectly. My domain/ip are not blacklisted. My header seems ok but still goes in hotmail anf ggole in the junk
here is my email header

```
x-store-info:4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kR0zqpsRfiBoybK3PQ6mULzhh/qStzTUBj1CiOy1ifpB5jRYvkVe516nq8df03m5lTTvFlpziq8EZP6IWKXOqJsDsIiQbuDS0q3AJ3AMTGnyocsnA9INLLlY0x93UPxgWHw==
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 216.246.45.58) smtp.mailfrom=event@eoman-ita.com; dkim=pass header.d=eoman-ita.com; x-hmca=pass header.id=event@eoman-ita.com
X-SID-PRA: event@eoman-ita.com
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD02
X-Message-Info: z6+tzUa3IoTSxtlwoUMYkGNdpCeLYkzDYtuP0/tvOrptl1UQvrig4LYPdRjCh4EVukMrJuorEq5iDHWLswthVz0ViHWKkAIrIM8CNQCcyZuIzAfTmL/k6p8YZ0qqD87cMH+yN4ch8Nm02Ni5VAILrn3rKXlZY8NMMa90cSkJGSFP6a8GjOgrNnFejkx8jAIdajiKd8xqKNhlnPL7JpC57E8f3jR1BJLc
Received: from server.reyam.net ([216.246.45.58]) by COL004-MC5F35.hotmail.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.22712);
     Tue, 4 Nov 2014 15:24:02 -0800
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=eoman-ita.com; s=default;
    h=Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:MIME-Version:Message-ID:Subject:Reply-To:From:To:Date; bh=AgYLBbYRXPLfqW6J+49c3YlpdLX4Gll2zXIu0mJI6i8=;
    b=QcUH74C2vNyKQj+2ajF9YwD0GbBmOjHrGzJHbofdFNOu8DGq0aWnvVOzAz5TRw/Mhp+6NaJL2jIGUkWVNcDUNbGgXUqJ3+CrAqGGUb/WDTy4N6nAl6h96Xgbsnbhan7aecInhMz7XnPU0R9b4hYM/huvOhvQS3KwALTlaiZkzxo=;
Received: from [216.246.45.58] (port=39807 helo=server.reyam.net)
    by server.reyam.net with esmtpsa (UNKNOWN:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256)
    (Exim 4.82)
    (envelope-from <event@eoman-ita.com>)
    id 1XlnSD-0007yy-R9
    for squ_1@hotmail.com; Wed, 05 Nov 2014 02:24:01 +0300
Date: Wed, 5 Nov 2014 03:24:01 +0400
To: Invitee <squ_1@hotmail.com>
From: ITA <event@eoman-ita.com>
Reply-To: ITA <info@eoman-ita.com>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?2KzYp9im2LLYqSDYp9mE2LPZhNi32KfZhiDZgtin2KjZiNizINmE2YTYpdis?=
 =?UTF-8?B?2KfYr9ipINmB2Yog2KfZhNiu2K/Zhdin2Kog2KfZhNit2YPZiNmF2YrYqSA=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?2KfZhNil2YTZg9iq2LHZiNmG2YrYqSBTdWx0YW4gUWFib29zIEF3YXJk?=
 =?UTF-8?B?IGZvciBFeGNlbGxlbmNlIGluIGVHb3Zlcm5tZW50?=
Message-ID: <2f438668313c88bbcc9616ca0a5a0442@server.reyam.net>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.9 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_2f438668313c88bbcc9616ca0a5a0442"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - server.reyam.net
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - hotmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - eoman-ita.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: server.reyam.net: authenticated_id: event@eoman-ita.com
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: 
X-Source-Dir: 
Return-Path: event@eoman-ita.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 04 Nov 2014 23:24:02.0749 (UTC) FILETIME=[6B5B5ED0:01CFF886]

--b1_2f438668313c88bbcc9616ca0a5a0442
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

Hi my frind. I wanw to say hi to you


--b1_2f438668313c88bbcc9616ca0a5a0442
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<p><img src="http://eoman-ita.com/smartevent/images/invet.jpg" /></p>
```

Comment: Does it happens only with Hotmail or also with Gmail and Yahoo?

Comment: You have no real control over this. Spam filters are completely arbitrary, and even if you have SPF and DKIM, and send innocuous content, it can be classified as spam.

Comment: Actually on the innocuous content front you'll be marked down because your message body is all images, no text - that's a classic spammer pattern that's worth avoiding.

Comment: It happens with Hotmail and Google. Not because of the content because I tried text only with same result.
We are a Government and sending invitation with a web application that use phpmailer to deliver that emails. From the header I have post what is wrong?

Comment: As an information, I currently have in my Firewall a rule saying that if an header of type "X-Mailer" contains "PHPMailer 5.2.9" I completely block the source IP.  We are receving SPAM mails of all type and from IPs all over the world and a good percentage of the SPAM is from such type of mail.  Is it possible that PHPMailer 5.2.9 has a security vulnerability or bad default parameters?